# Getting Winter Time in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

We are now in the summer time (UTC+01:00) but I need always winter time whereever I am.

For example now time is 08:05 and winter time is 07:05

I can find whether it is saving time or not by using this function

```
DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime()
```

and here is the delta (1 hour change)

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetAdjustmentRules()[0].DaylightDelta;
```

so if I do something like that, is it correct?

```
var winterTime= DateTime.Now;
if (DateTime.Now.IsDaylightSavingTime())
{
  winterTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1 * delta.Hours);
}
```

or is there another way to do? (without using any 3rd solution)

Edit: The reason why I am asking this is that we are flashing a firmware to a nfc device and some dates in the devices should be in winter time. Thats why our tool should write winter time as paramter to the device.

Comment: _I need always winter time_ There is no such thing.

Comment: @TaW I have to find it out. (I've edited my question, you can see the reason) just was not sure whether this logic is fine or not. Thank you

Comment: Just correcting the terms. There is normal time and dst (aka summer time).

Comment: "some dates in the devices should be in winter time" - please clarify *exactly* what you mean by this. Why would a date in the summer use the non-DST offset for whatever time zone you're using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case `DaylightDelta` is not whole hours better use the TimeSpan directly. Also you need to find the rule in `GetAdjustmentRules()` that matches the current date. `GetAdjustmentRules()` returns both future and historical rules.

```
var now = DateTime.Today;
var rule = TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetAdjustmentRules().Where(x => now >= x.DateStart && now <= x.DateEnd).First();
winterTime = DateTime.Now - rule.DaylightDelta;
```

Comment: thank you but is it a good way to do it? I am not sure regarding calculation and my logic..

Comment: There are some time zones that are half our or 45 minutes. Perhaps there are some Daylight Saving adjustments that are that as well. In any case, this would be a safer way of doing it.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I will continue with that then.

Comment: Using the `[0]` in `TimeZoneInfo.Local.GetAdjustmentRules()[0]` is wrong. You need to ensure that the `AdjustmentRule` you pick from the `AdjustmentRule[]` array is currently valid by checking the `DateStart` and `DateEnd` properties.

Comment: @Magnus - The last one might not be the currently valid one. The rules might have a future rule.

Comment: @Magnus - There's still one wobbly. The `DateEnd` property has a value like `2007-12-31 00:00:00` and the `DateStart` like `2008-01-01 00:00:00`, so if you don't specifically use date only comparisons then the `Where` rule you've used can still fail.

Answer (score 1):

> We are now in the summer time (UTC+01:00) but I need always winter time whereever I am.
>
> ...
>
> ... The reason why I am asking this is that we are flashing a firmware to a nfc device and some dates in the devices should be in winter time. Thats why our tool should write winter time as paramter to the device.

It sounds like you simply want to obtain the UTC time to set on the device.  If so, just use `DateTime.UtcNow`.  There is no need to concern yourself with time zones.

However, if you actually wanted to take the standard time (or winter time) for whatever local time zone you're in (that would seem to be a bit silly because that's not how local times work), but if you ***really*** are sure you want that, you can do it without querying adjustment rules.  Instead, try this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset).DateTime;
```

This takes the current UTC time, applies the *base* offset of the local time zone, and then gives you back a `DateTime` with `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`.  The base offset is the offset from UTC that applies during standard time without any adjustment rules applied for DST.